# neo4j how to config master and slave for HA?

Tags: neo4j, high-availability

I am trying to add HA on the same machine like in this article:

http://aws-labs.com/neo4j-high-availability-setup-tutorial/

("Alternative setup: Creating a local cluster for testing")

When I started to open all locations only :7474 opened.

:7475 and :7476 show me "This site can’t be reached".

All config files look like this:

```
 # Name of the service
 dbms.windows_service_name=neo4j
 # With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
 # To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
 dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
 # Reduce the default page cache memory allocation
 dbms.pagecache.memory=500m
 # Port to listen to for incoming backup requests.
 online_backup_server = 10.234.10.94:6366
 # Unique server id for this Neo4j instance
 # can not be negative id and must be unique
 ha.server_id = 1
 # List of other known instances in this cluster
 ha.initial_hosts = 10.234.10.94:5001,10.234.10.94:5002,10.234.10.94:5003
 # IP and port for this instance to bind to for communicating cluster 
 information
 # with the other neo4j instances in the cluster.
 ha.cluster_server = 10.234.10.94:5001
 # IP and port for this instance to bind to for communicating data with the
 # other neo4j instances in the cluster.
 ha.server = 10.234.10.94:6363
 # HA - High Availability
 # SINGLE - Single mode, default.
 org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA
 # http port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
 dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
 org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474
 # https port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
 dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
 org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7484
```

And how I should config the master?

Comment: Have you read/try this : http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/local-highly-available-cluster/ ?

Comment: @logisima yes, i did the same, and i have next logs: ` 
2018-02-08 06:59:22.723+0000 INFO  Write transactions to database disabled
2018-02-08 06:59:23.181+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2018-02-08 06:59:23.193+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics...
2018-02-08 06:59:25.075+0000 INFO  Attempting to join cluster of [10.234.10.94:5001, 10.234.10.94:5002, 10.234.10.94:5003]
2018-02-08 07:00:56.316+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@497aec8c' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. `

Comment: Do you have anything else into the `log/debug.log` ? A stacktrace for example ?

Comment: oh, checked the debug.log and found smth interesting with ports, will try to fix my mistakes)) thanks for idea !!!   @logisima